# Communication with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a class that does not extend `Activity` (and can't because it extends `CursorAdapter`) The `CursorAdapter` needs to communicate back with the fragment that it populates, more specifically in each list item there is a button, whenever that button is clicked I need it to refresh the list and to do this I need to call `getFragmentManager()`.

My Problem: because I am extending `CursorAdapter` I can't call `getFragmentManager()` (it must be called from a fragment or an activity.)

What I have tried.
The first thing I thought to do (and it might be right and I just botched the implementation due to my lack of java skills) is to create a class that extends Activity that would interface with my fragment for the cursor adapter. CODE:

```
public class FragManager extends Activity {

   public FragManager() {
   }

    public void refreshList() {

        QCListFragment fragmentB = (QCListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment);
        fragmentB.requeryList();
    }


}
```

this was called inside my cursor adapter like this. CODE:

```
FragManager fragment = new FragManager();
            fragment.refreshList();
```

Anyhow, I think this is the right line of thought but was unable to find tutorials (maybe because I did not know what words to use to search for it)

Any help would be wonderful!
Marek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your code structure right now, but if any of your classes are nested, you can access the containing class, like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();

    public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        public MyAdapter() {
            FragmentManager fm = MyActivity.this.getFragmentManager();
        }
    }
}
```

If nesting is not in use, then you can pass an instance of a class directly to the class that needs to access it.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
}

public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Activity activity, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(activity, c, flags);
        FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: No nesting. All my code is attached up top. I'm not sure I understand your non-nested example... it sounds like what I want to do but I'm not understanding how I should implement. when I implement the second section (MyAdapter in your example I get something like this)  `public CalcCursorAdapter(Activity activity) {
  FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
 }` and gives me this complaint `Implicit super constructor CursorAdapter() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor`

Comment: i edited the example to show how to call one of the super constructors.  these details (which other parameters you accept and which super constructor you call) can be changed to fit your situation.

Comment: This returned a null pointer error but I will have to mess with it more after class and will update you on how it goes.

Comment: You probably can't call `getFragmentManager()` from the constructor like this, but if you save the `Activity` you should be able to use it from your button click handler.

Comment: Ok, so here is my code...
`public CalcCursorAdapter(FragManager activity, Cursor c, int flags) {
  super(activity, c, flags);
  mActivity = activity;
  
 }`

and in the `OnClick`
`Fragment fragmentB = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment);
         ((QCListFragment) fragmentB).requeryList();` This still gives me a null pointer...

Comment: get rid of your `FragManager` nonsense and pass in an actual running Activity.  from a fragment, you can call `getActivity()` to retrieve this value.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call `requeryList()` from that `Activity`?

First, I your `Activity` should extend `FragmentActivity`.

Here is how you call that method in all situations:

```
((QCListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment)).requeryList();
```

Call method from `Fragment` in a `Fragment`:

```
((QCListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment)).requeryList();
```

Call method from `FragmentActivity` in a `Fragment`:

```
((QCLisActivity) getActivity()).requeryList();
```

Comment: I have everything to communicate with my fragment set in place... I just need to be able to all a function inside another class.

Comment: I just showed you got to call a function from another FragmentActivity as well as Fragment.